# Network neighborhood can't see shared move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

After an image is uploaded with PHP, I want to make the image can copy by neighbors in explorer.exe so server shared it's D:\xampp\htdocs and here is the code.

```
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$upload_file_name]['tmp_name'], $dir_base.$newFileName);

if (file_exists(realpath($dir_base . $newFileName))) {
  error_log("\n realpath \n".print_r(  realpath($dir_base.$newFileName) ,true)."\n".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n",3,"html_cache/saveData.html");
  //will echo D:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\data1\bg\1812061109410.png

  chmod( realpath($dir_base . $newFileName),0644);
}
```

chmod is not working. Security has only Administrator without Everyone and System.

If I right click on xampp/tmp and add Everyone's security to it. It works fine but how can I make this by pure php?

Comment: If I remember correctly, chmod didn't work on Windows environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sakura Kinomoto said, chmod doesn't work on Windows environment.
Use cacls.

```
exec('echo Y|cacls '.realpath($dir_base . $newFileName).' /E /G Everyone:R');
```